# How to fix cmake install in Jupyter kernels, specifically Google Colab?

Tags: cmake, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am trying to get OpenAI roboschool to run in Google Colab (have a virtual display setup that records the environment during training and displays video after). The roboschool library will import, but the environments don't show up properly (at all), when I run:

```
import roboschool, gym; 
print("\n".join(['- ' + spec.id for spec in 
gym.envs.registry.all() if spec.id.startswith('Roboschool')]))
```

the list is empty, and it should include the environments.

When cmake links dlls, does it do so with environment variables? Environment variables in Colab don't work as usual, and I think that may be the issue. I don't know enough to know for sure.

This output looks suspect to me, doesn't seem right that the runtime path would be removed. There are a number of these so I only grabbed two for example.

```
-- Set runtime path of "/content/roboschool/roboschool/cpp- 
household/bullet_local_install/lib/libBulletDynamics.so.2.87" to "" 
-- Set runtime path of "/content/roboschool/roboschool/cpp- 
household/bullet_local_install/lib/libBullet3Geometry.so.2.87" to "
```

Here is the command sequence.

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DUSE_DOUBLE_PRECISION=1 - 
  DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/content/roboschool/roboschool/cpp- 
  household/bullet_local_install -DBUILD_CPU_DEMOS=OFF - 
  DBUILD_BULLET2_DEMOS=OFF -DBUILD_EXTRAS=OFF  -DBUILD_UNIT_TESTS=OFF - 
  DBUILD_CLSOCKET=OFF -DBUILD_ENET=OFF -DBUILD_OPENGL3_DEMOS=OFF ..
make -j4
make install
```

Is there a way I can override the way paths are determined for the linked libraries so they will link with the correct paths if that is correct? Seems like looking into RPATH may be a step in the right direction?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if additional detail is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's going on without more details, but if you're building .so's to non-standard location that you want the python runtime to see, you have to somehow tell the runtime about the .so's location. Guessing based on the snippets you provided, maybe this (possibly after a runtime restart (ctrl-m-period)) will unblock you:

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/content/roboschool/roboschool/cpp-household/bullet_local_install/lib:' + os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
```

If that doesn't do it for you, two other suggestions are:

1. Change your configuration to install to "standard" locations
2. Share a minimal notebook that reproduces the issue.